# Let $f$ be a continuous function for non-(-ve) numbers such that $f(2n)= f(f(n))$ and $f(2n+1)=f(2n)+1,$ find $f(n)$ for every $n$ if $f(0)=0.$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Well I found this question in a magazine(JEE related in India). The question hasn't specified what $n$ actually is. Am assuming that $n\in\mathbb N\cup\{0\}.$ My observations so far:

$f(2n)=f(f(n))\tag{1}.$

$f(2n+1)=f(2n)+1\tag{2}.$

Putting $n=0$ in $(2),$ we get $f(1)=1,$ as $f(0)=0.$

Putting $n=1$ in $(1)$, we get $f(2)=1.$

Putting $n=1$ in $(2),$ we have $f(3)=2.$

Putting $n=2$ in $(1)$, we get $f(4)=1.$

Putting $n=2$ in $(2),$ we obtain $f(5)=2$ and so on...

Based on these observations, we can write:

$f(n)=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }n=0\\\\1,&\text{if }n=1\\\\1,&\text{if }n\text{ is even number(+ve) other than 0}\\\\2,&\text{if }n\text{ is odd number(+ve) other than 1}.\end{cases}$

But it is given that $f(n)$ is continuous for all non-negative numbers and the above form surely doesn't ensure continuity of $f(n)$. So how to deal with this problem? Please suggest.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any function over $\mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$ is continuous.

Comment: Oh okay! But what about the form of $f(n)$ ? According to my form of $f(n),$ there is a jump in the value of $f$ when we move from $n=0$ to $n=1$. Still can we consider $f(n)$ to be continuous?

Comment: Also $f(7)$ would have to be $3$ and not $2$ like you suggest.

Comment: $f(7) = 1 + f(6) = 1 + f(f(3)) = 1 + f(2) = 1 + 1 = 2$

Comment: As mentioned above, any function on discrete space like N is continuous topologically. There is a different and occasionally convenient notion of continuity for functions $f$: N -> N, namely $| f(n+1) - f(n) | <= 1$. The point is that such functions satisfy the intermediate value theorem, which can be useful in some types of problems. And the function in this problem is continuous in this sense as well.

Comment: @Ned, Oh, haven't read topology so didn't know such a notion of continuity exists. So that means the form I have shown is correct, no further modifications needed, right?

Comment: @DhrubajyotiBhattacharjee I don't know what notion of continuity they had in mind, since it's vacuously trivial for ordinary (topological) continuity in the example here, and in any case it's irrelevant for computing the function defined by the recursion. So, the continuity part of the question just doesn't make sense to me, period.